# MPL 2.0 in perspective of game development and selling

Tags: licensing

I am planning to use a math library named [Eigen3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ) which is under [MPL 2.0](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/2.0).
 However, I am not sure what MPL 2.0 means.

As a game developer, who want to sell `game.exe` (probably by Steam or GoG) who does not wish to distribute source `.h`/`.cpp`, here is what I understand MPL 2.0 :-

1. I have to tell the buyers of my game that I use **Eigen3**, and provide a reasonable-and-almost-free way (how? Is attaching a description `.txt` enough?)  to download code of **Eigen3**.
2. If I just call some functions of **Eigen3** and I don't modify any part of the library, I don't have to distribute any of modification of anything.
3. There are no other obligation.

### **Question**

1. How should I provide them source code of **Eigen3** *in practice*?
2. Is there any wrong about my understanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the best site to get legal advice (not sure if the SE legal site is good for game licenses either).

I used [TLDRlicense for MPL 2.0](https://tldrlegal.com/license/mozilla-public-license-2.0-(mpl-2)). Based on what it says, the answers to your questions are:

1. You should provide them a link. Something like "You can download the source code for Eigen3 at http://eigen.tuxfamily.org" (or whatever the right URL is)
2. No, your understanding is correct.

The "usual" way to do this is provide a `license.txt` or `credits` file/screen (or something similar) which lists all copyright-related things. Here's where you can provide the link and notice about Eigen3.

Comment: Good answer!   By the way, what are good legal sites for (game) programmers in your mind?

Comment: @javaLover The open source stack exchange, http://opensource.stackexchange.com

Comment: @javaLover: At least for Open Source Licenses. For proprietary licenses, try the [law.se] Stack Exchange. We used to also take software licensing questions on [softwareengineering.se], but since the creation of those two, we have become much more strict, for the simple reason that we are programmers, not lawyers, and thus simply not equipped to answer such questions.

Comment: Providing a mention in the EULA would work as well.

Comment: @ashes999 No, post a mention about Eigen3 in the EULA of the to-be-sold program.

Comment: @Mast ah, that makes sense.